# Access field in non public class through reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to access private field mRadialTimePickerModeButton in android.widget.TimePickerClockDelegate

TimePickerClockDelegate is a non public class extending TimePicker.AbstractTimePickerDelegate which implements TimePicker.TimePickerDelegate

I cannot make a new instance of this, I need to modify that field on this particular instance.

I tried accessing it like this:

```
Field field = TimePickerDialog.class.getDeclaredField("mTimePicker");
field.setAccessible(true);
TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) field.get(this);

Field delegateField = TimePicker.class.getDeclaredField("mDelegate");
delegateField.setAccessible(true);
Object delegate = delegateField.get(timePicker);

Field buttonField = delegate.getClass().getDeclaredField("mRadialTimePickerModeButton");
buttonField.setAccessible(true);
ImageButton radialTimePickerModeButton = (ImageButton) buttonField.get(delegate);
```

Getting: No field mRadialTimePickerModeButton in class Landroid/widget/TimePickerClockDelegate; (declaration of 'android.widget.TimePickerClockDelegate' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes4.dex)

Comment: How do you know the field exist? The error seem to indicate that there is so filed of that name, so may be you were looking at code that is not installed on your device.